# I cannot find the correct image (.jpg) through webdriver, selenium, and beautifulsoup

Tags: python, selenium, webdriver

I am trying to download few hundreds photos from the following website:(https://www.strongmotioncenter.org/cgi-bin/CESMD/Multiplesearch1_DM2.pl?event_name=&magmin=&magmax=&byear=&eyear=&country=Any&state=Any&stn_ident=&type=BLD&Material=Concrete&Height=&siteclass=Any&accmin=&accmax=&hdistmin=&hdistmax=)

You can see the link under **station-column**, which I want to automatically click it and find the **jpg (left-hand side)** file in the new browser then download it.

I use the jupyter notebook to write my python code, as shown below:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import urllib.request
import requests
chrome=webdriver.Chrome('/Users/user/Downloads/software
/chromedriver_win32/chromedriver')

chrome.get("https://www.strongmotioncenter.org/cgi-
bin/CESMD/Multiplesearch1_DM2.pl?
event_name=&magmin=&magmax=&byear=&eyear
=&country=Any&state=Any&stn_ident=&type=BLD&Material
=Concrete&Height=&siteclass=Any&accmin=&accmax=&hdistmin=&hdistmax=")

stations = chrome.find_element_by_css_selector('.xlink')
stations.click()
url_link = chrome.current_url
soup = BeautifulSoup(urllib.request.urlopen(url_link),"lxml")
figure = soup.find_all('.jpg')
print(figure)
```

It always print out nothing. However if I write:

```
figure = soup.find_all('img')
```

It will return:

```
[<img onclick="url(&quot;'+" processed="" 
src="../../NCESMD/images/save_32.gif"/>, <img onclick="url(&quot;'+" raw="" 
src="../../NCESMD/images/save_32.gif"/>]
```

Which is not the image file that I want.

I really have no idea what is going on.

Thanks for the time. I really appreciate that.

Comment: Have a look at the site using the browser F12 tools. Look at the network activity and the usage of JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

I tried in Java, you could use the same approach.

First of all we have to get all the web elements with class name **xlink**

```
    List<WebElement> xlinks = driver.findElements(By.className("xlink"));
```

For each of these elements, we have to create the *Station selected* url.
In order to do this, we know that an url is something like this:

> https://www.strongmotioncenter.org/cgi-bin/CESMD/stationhtml.pl?staID=CE34234&network=CGS

The first part is "static":

```
String stationSelectUrl = "https://www.strongmotioncenter.org/cgi-bin/CESMD/stationhtml.pl?";
```

The second one no:

```
staID=CE34234&network=CGS
```

The info about the second part are in the **"onclick"** attribute.

In this example:

```
onclick="openwin('CE34234','CGS')"
```

So, with this info we can create all the intrested url.

For each of these url, we have to get the web element that contain the imageurl and download it:

```
            WebElement img = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font/a/img"));
            String imageid = img.getAttribute("src");
            downloadFile(imageid);
```

In order to download the file, I used the *curl* command.

The entire code:

```
public class SeleniumTest {
public static void main(String args[]) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, InterruptedException {
        WebDriver driver;
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
        String vURL = "https://www.strongmotioncenter.org/cgi-bin/CESMD/Multiplesearch1_DM2.pl?event_name=&magmin=&magmax=&byear=&eyear=&country=Any&state=Any&stn_ident=&type=BLD&Material=Concrete&Height=&siteclass=Any&accmin=&accmax=&hdistmin=&hdistmax=";
        driver.get(vURL);
        List<WebElement> xlinks = driver.findElements(By.className("xlink"));
        int i = 1;
        String stationSelectUrl = "https://www.strongmotioncenter.org/cgi-bin/CESMD/stationhtml.pl?";

        WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
        for (WebElement xlink : xlinks) {
            System.out.println(xlink.getText());
            String onclick = xlink.getAttribute("onclick");
            System.out.println("onclick: " + onclick);
            String relativeUrl = getStationSelected(onclick);
            System.out.println("relativeUrl: " + relativeUrl);
            System.out.println("------------" + i + "------------------");
            i++;
            driver2.get(stationSelectUrl + relativeUrl);
            driver2.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

            WebElement img = driver2.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/center/table/tbody/tr[1]/td[1]/font/a/img"));
            String imageid = img.getAttribute("src");
            downloadFile(imageid);

        }

        driver2.close();
        driver.close();
    }


    private static String getStationSelected(String onclick) {
        StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(onclick, "'");
        st.nextToken();
        String statID = st.nextToken();
        st.nextToken();
        String network = st.nextToken();
        onclick = "staID=" + statID + "&network=" + network;
        return onclick;
    }

    private static void downloadFile(String file) {
        try {
            String[] CMD_COMPOSED = {
                    "/bin/bash",
                    "-c",
                    "curl -O " + file,};

            Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(CMD_COMPOSED);
            System.out.println("File " + file + " downloaded!");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: Thank you so much！I already solved the problem but I still use python's selemium and the webdriver to download photos. I really appreciate your time and codes, I will try to modify my code and try to use javascript ( I just have few experience on javascript.)